# Mongodb/sails find(): distinct records with pagination

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

scenario:

documents need to be fetched by a page limit of 20 , sorted in descending order.
The returned results need to be unique ( id, title etc , based on a property)

consider the possibility that item A on page 1 can have a duplicate on page 2 .

is there a query that can handle this kind of a situation ?

It seems not possible in Sails waterline , but I'm wondering whether a native call to mongo can solve this .

Comment: What do you mean by unique in mongo? Like, if you are looking for unique titles, and there are 5 records with the same title property, do you take the first one? Do some sort of summation of another property? Also not sure what you mean by duplicate on page 2 - how does that work with uniqueness?

Comment: Let's say that there are two documents that have the same title .by pages I meant limiting results by let's say 20 . So the problem here is that let's say in the first set of results I got a document of which I know that in the next 20 results there is another document with the same title . How do I make sure that the second document is skipped while also make sure that after excluding this document I'm still able to fetch and send 20 documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think mongo can do what you want here. It looks like you can use mongo's [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) command to get distinct values of a given property across a collection, or across the result of a query (and sails exposes raw mongo queries via [`.native`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native)).

However, this may not be useful if you want the whole representative object, not just the single property with distinctness. It also doesn't let you query in a way that you are guaranteed a certain number of distinct values.

I think you will be forced to make this work in code if it must work. One ugly way is to fetch "more than enough" records (30? 100?) to be reasonably sure of 20 distinct values, and pick through then in a loop until you get 20. To implement pagination, you could use the field you are sorting on (this would work if that field is also the unique field, or not.

An example api call for a collection with fields `title` and `popularity` (for example), where we want distinct titles, and are sorting by `popularity DESC`: (this code would be in module.exports of some controller)

```
getMoreRecords: function(req, res) {
    var foundTitles = req.param('foundTitles'); // an array of titles we already have
    var lowestPop = req.param('lowestPop'); // the lowest popularity already retrieved
    Record.find({
        title: {'!': foundTitles},
        popularity: {'<': lowestPop}
    }).limit(100).sort('popularity DESC').exec(function(err, records) {
        // do the error handling...
        var filteredRecords = records.filter(function(rec, idx, arr) {
            return arr.indexOf(rec) === idx;
        });
        // filteredRecords is guaranteed to contain records with unique, unseen titles in popularity desc order
        // it could contain any number however
        return res.json(filteredRecords.slice(0,20));
    });
}
```

This requires sending back all titles found already to the server for every new page. To avoid that, you could do some of this client-side, but it gets increasingly complicated.

In general, I would recommend keeping "more than enough" records client-side (like, multiple pages worth), and querying when you need more, maybe after a few pages. And I would do any filtering of already-seen titles client side, rather than on the server as I've show here.

Comment: yeah , I just thought about the very same thing .. fetching more records than needed and the filtering out . works for me ! thanks !

Comment: I'm doing some work related research with mongo right now, and I may have spoken hastily in my answer. It looks like raw mongo queries do support grouping (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and operators that let you take the first representative (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/). You still can't use it through waterline, but you could push through to the raw mongo queries.